# Highlow/Candle Plot that works with Second Data

Tags: matlab

I have a data series where I am dealing with data that is at the second level (some datapoints are also in millisecond but not many, only when multiple points exist in same second).

I am trying to plot using either the candle or highlow plot functions.

Neither work properly.

highlow will space bars differently, candle does not work at all.

Any suggestions on a function which can plot candle charts and works with second level data?

Comment: Do you want to get the daily data from the data you have and then plot a candle chart? Or are you wanting to plot something on a finer timescale?

Comment: Minute data seems to work fine.  As soon as I add irregular spaced data e.g. volume bars, tick bars (unevenly spaced time intervals and some with millisecond timestamps) things break.  So my timescale is finer, not large.